# counting numbers with specific Quality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the count of 10 digit numbers with the exact sequences 72 and 081 in them with no repetition .
Is there any fast way to calculate this because of the 081 the places of 72 are limited and not coherent. For example placing 081 nearly at the end with 1 digit next to it potentially removes the ability to place 72 there

Comment: Well, first solve the problem assuming you allow $0$ to come first.  Can you see that that is just the number of permutations of $7$ letters?  Now exclude those in which $081$ comes at the start.

Comment: Hint: Try to use a recursion. How can you find the number of 4 digit ones in terms of the 2 digit or 1 digit ones? How about 4 to 7 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the number must contain $081$ and $72$, we have to count how many numbers are there containing "pieces": $081$, $72$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $9$ with no repetitions. There are $7$ pieces, so if we allowed the number to start with $081$, the pieces could be arranged in $7!$ ways. However, as the number cannot start with $081$, we can place any of the $6$ remaining pieces in the first position, any of the $6$ pieces (the remaining ones and $081$) in the second position, any of the $5$ pieces in the third position and so on.

We conclude that there are therefore $6\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ such numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Stick $081$ together, ditto for $72$, then $5$ other single digits remain.

These "blocks" can be permuted in $7!$ ways but a *number* can't start with a $0$, so multiply by the Pr that the $081$ block is not at the start to get $\left(\dfrac6 7 \cdot 7!\right)$