# What's the probability of A and B being at most 1 person apart out of 12 randomly positioned persons?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I'm checking if I'm approaching this problem correctly. The problem: there are 12 people seated in a row. Their positions are randomly determined. How likely is it that persons A and B have at most 1 person between them?

Now, it's trivial to just brute force it by visualising how many people there are. There are 11 ways for them to be next to one another and 10 ways to be one apart. For 12 people, there's a total of 12C2 = 66 two person combinations. Ergo P(A) = (11+10)/66 = 21/66 = approx. 31,8%.

My main question is if there's a proper mathematical way to determine the number of combinations in which the two people are either adjacent or one apart, or if I should just use visual aids in situations like this?

Comment: What do you find "*improper*" about the approach you used?  It seems perfectly proper to me.

Comment: You mention "brute force", but I don't think that's what this is. The real brute force approach would be: $\frac{|\{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \ldots, \{11,12\}\}|}{|\{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{1,5\}, \ldots, \{11,12\}\}|} = \frac{21}{66} = \frac27$. Now imagine there are $1000$ people instead of $12$, and compare the two approaches.

Comment: The idea of your approach is fine, and as Théophile says, it’s not “brute force.” I would take care to note that for any one choice of the two positions for A and B, there are exactly the same number of arrangements of the $12$ people (two choices for whether A or B is first times $10!$ choices for how the others are arranged in the remaining positions.) As “how likely” refers to distinct arrangements and your (valid) approach considers just the different pairs of positions that could be occupied up by A and B, you should address the difference.

Comment: Mmhm, okay, thanks. So I suppose this really is a clean way to go about this. Thanks to you all. I guess it can be generalised that there's n-1 two unit adjacent groups and n-2 three unit adjacent groups and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler (and less "visual") to use the concepts of *blocks*

For example, if there are $20$ people, and you want the particular two to have $4$ people in between, you have one block of $6$ people and the balance $14$ as blocks of $1$ each.

Here, you only have one block with more than one person, but more complex problems might have more complex situations in which using blocks would prove useful

And then, if *Pr* is asked for, you can decide whether you want to use combinations or permutations (to take care that the numerator and denominator are of the same type) and proceed.

Comment: You might like to have a look at a question I answered a day back to better get what I am driving at. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052660/counting-numbers-with-specific-quality/4053233#4053233